# How to connect QQuickitem with Qml Object?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to make a simple program that allow user to connect to the specific websites via clicking the image.
Here is my code:

account.h:

```
#ifndef ACCOUNTS_H
#define ACCOUNTS_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDesktopServices>
class accounts : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit accounts(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent){}
public slots:

void gmailOpen(const QString &msg)
{
    QUrl gmailUrl(msg);
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(gmailUrl);
}
};
#endif // ACCOUNTS_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQml>
#include "accounts.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    QObject *gmail = view->rootObject().findChild<QObject*>("gmailLink");
    accounts *gmailAccount = new accounts;
    QObject::connect(gmail, SIGNAL(gmailSignal(QString)),gmailAccount,SLOT(gmailOpen(QString)));
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/yudelin/Documents/MyCrazyProjects/Managers4ManyAccounts/main.qml"));
    view->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {

    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "silver"

    Image {
        id:gmailLink
        objectName: "gmailLink"
        width: 102
        height: 199
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source: "...." //the url is too long so I omit it.
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        signal gmaiSignal (string msg)
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:
                gmailLink.gmailSignal("http://mail.google.com")
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am trying to connect Qml Image with c++ object accounts.
So I use `QObject *gmail = view->rootObject().findChild<QObject*>("gmailLink");` to fetch the qml object.
But it does not work. I guess it is suit for the older Qt version.
How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You want gmailOpen slot to be called on clicking on the Image. There are simpler and preferred ways of doing it other than doing this.

   QObject *gmail = view->rootObject().findChild("gmailLink");
2. As @Kunal pointed out, you can use `Qt.openUrlExternally(string)`.
3. If you want to open the Url by using `QDesktopServices::openUrl` from the `gmailOpen` slot, you can call the slot directly by setting the context property.

4, `QObject *gmail = view->rootObject().findChild<QObject*>("gmailLink");`... Here before setting the qml file, you are trying to get a reference for the `gmailLink` object. Its not created yet.

5. Following code explains my take on the problem

   5a. accounts.h file

---

```
#ifndef ACCOUNTS_H
#define ACCOUNTS_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDesktopServices>
class accounts : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit accounts(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent){}
public slots:

void gmailOpen(const QString &msg)
{
    QUrl gmailUrl(msg);
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(gmailUrl);
}
};
#endif // ACCOUNTS_H
```

5b. main.cpp file

---

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQml>
#include "accounts.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    accounts *gmailAccount = new accounts;
    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("accounts",gmailAccount);
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("qml/SO_OpenExternalLink/main.qml"));
    view->show();
    return app.exec();
}

5c. main.qml file
```

---

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "silver"
    Image {
        id:gmailLink
        objectName: "gmailLink"
        width: 102
        height: 199
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:Qt.openUrlExternally("http://mail.google.com")
        }
    }
    Image{
        id:secondImage
        width:102
        height:199
        fillMode:Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Emblem_of_India.svg"
        anchors.left:gmailLink.right
        anchors.top: gmailLink.top
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:fileDialog.visible = true
        }
    }
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Please choose a file"
        nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.jpg *.png)", "All files (*)" ]
        visible:false;
        selectMultiple:false
        onAccepted:secondImage.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
    }

}
```

---

5d. You need to change the following from the above code

i. Image source

ii.  QML file path in the main.cpp

iii.  Possibly import QtQuick 2.0 if you don't have QtQuick 2.1 yet.

Comment: Please note that if you have the account class solely for opening URL, then I suggest you to drop the class and use `Qt.openUrlExternally(string)` instead .

Comment: I would like to add more features on click action.
So I think I would like to bind c++ class and qml objects.
Thanks for your help for modifying my code.
But I have some question about engine. 
Is it a handler for qml to control c++ objects?

Comment: `view->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("accounts",gmailAccount);`
seems set every qml having the same feature.
What if I want to make some of them have their own specific feature,
How could I do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understood your question correctly. * What if I want to make some of them have their own specific feature*.  Can you explain it in detail please? Do you want create a C++ class and use it as new type in QML? Please explain it with an example to help us help you.

Comment: If I create two images in the qml, I want both of them having different functions. For instance, I click image 1 to open a new web page and I click image 2 to change its image. How could I do?

Comment: If you just need to change the image on clicking an image, you need not do anything special in C++ side. You probably need to do this

1)Add this statement `import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0`
2)Add a [FileDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickdialogs/qml-qtquick-dialogs1-filedialog.html) component to your main.qml file
3)Whenever you click on second image show the file dialog
4)On selecting an image file, you get the `accepted` signal on handling which you can access the filename
5)Change the image source and set the filename as image source

Comment: Well, could you make an easy example of how to use FileDialog?
I have no idea how to use that function.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show the usage of FileDialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to open URL then you can use `Qt.openUrlExternally(string)` directly from QML. [Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-qt.html#openurlexternally) is documentation. No need to create a QObject for this.

And for your code. I don't see any method named `gmailSignal`.
You should be calling `gmailOpen`.

like

```
gmailLink.gmailOpen("http://mail.google.com")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
But I really want to learn how to bind QML and c++ together.
That is why I want to use the signals and slots.
By the way, I have declared gmailSignal, but I miss the l 
Sorry for confusing you.